# How to deal with Part in a function?

Tags: core-language, simulation

I need to iterate several functions such as `{3 x[[1]]^2 + x[[2]], x[[2]], x[[3]]}`, `{Exp[x[[4]]], x[[2]], x[[3]], x[[4]]}`,etc. The number of variables depends on the problem I need to solve.

Here is an example:

```
ClearAll[aux]; 
aux[f_, α_, n_] := 
  Module[{g},
    g = Quiet @ Table[If[k == 1, f - α Random[] x[[k]], x[[k]]], {k, 1, n}];
    g]

ClearAll[fun]; 
fun[x_] = aux[3 x[[2]], 2, 3]

ClearAll[simul]; 
simul[f_, length_: 1, ic_] := Module[{i}, NestList[f[#] &, ic, length]]

simul[fun, 2, RandomReal[1, 3]]
```

Despite the warning message

> Part::partd: Part specification x[[2]] is longer than depth of object

which can be suppressed, the above sequence of functions works (if somebody has a better solution, please let me know).

Unfortunately when I try to put everything together under a function, it won't work. For instance

```
trajec[f_, α_, n_] := 
  Module[{fun, orb},
    fun[x_] = Quiet @ aux[f, α, n];
    orb = simul[fun, n, RandomReal[1, n]];
    Table[{i, orb[[i]]}, {i, 1, n}]]

trajec[3 x[[2]], 2, 3]
```

returns

> ```
> {1, {0.561078, 0.450353, 0.243782}}, 
> {2, {-0.198531 x[[1]] + 3 x[[2]], x[[2]], x[[3]]}}, 
> {3, {-0.198531 x[[1]] + 3 x[[2]], x[[2]], x[[3]]}}}
> ```

and not actual values.

What am I missing?

Comment: You will only get numeric results when you define a List x that contains numeric values otherwise x will be treated as a symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are missing, I believe, is sufficient experience of *Mathematica*'s core language at the functional level that you experimenting with. I give you credit for making a good try at formulating your code in a functional way, but I'm afraid you gone somewhat wide of the mark.

I have put your code into a form that works and which I think preserves your intent. I am not at all sure I have got it right because I find your intent obscure, so I hope you tell me if I am any closer to the mark than you were.

```
aux[f_, α_, x_List] :=
  Table[If[k == 1, f[x] - α RandomReal[] x[[k]], x[[k]]], {k, 1, Length[x]}]
fun[x_List] := aux[3 #[[2]] &, 2, x]
simul[f_, ic_, length_: 1] := NestList[f, ic, length]

SeedRandom[42]; simul[fun, RandomReal[1, 3], 2]
```

> ```
> {{0.425905, 0.391023, 0.347069}, 
>  {0.786568, 0.391023, 0.347069}, 
>  {0.298463, 0.391023, 0.347069}}
> ```

#### Update

I do not recommend putting everything under one function. Rather, I would generalize the restricted case shown above as follows.

```
aux[f_, α_, x_] := 
 Table[If[k == 1, f[x] - α RandomReal[] x[[k]], x[[k]]], {k, 1, Length[x]}]

fun[α_, x_] := aux[3 #[[2]] &, α, x]
```

I write `traject` so that the length of the random vectors, `len` is decoupled from the number on iterations, `n`.

```
traject[f : (_Function | _Symbol), α_?NumericQ, 
        len_Integer /; len > 0, n_Integer /; n > 0] :=
  Module[{vec = RandomReal[1, len], i = 0, next, result},
    result = {0, vec};
    Nest[(result = {result, {++i, next = f[α, #]}}; next) &, vec, n];
    Cases[result, {_Integer, _List}, ∞]]
```

Now results such as the following can be computed.

```
 SeedRandom[42]; traject[fun, 2, 3, 3]
```

> ```
> {{0, {0.425905, 0.391023, 0.347069}}, 
>  {1, {0.786568, 0.391023, 0.347069}}, 
>  {2, {0.298463, 0.391023, 0.347069}}, 
>  {3, {1.00046, 0.391023, 0.347069}}}
> ```

The above is what you asked for. But many variants are possible, including the obvious: varying the number of iterations, varying the length of the generated vectors, and varying the value of `α`.

```
 SeedRandom[42]; traject[fun, 2, 3, 1]
```

> ```
> {{0, {0.425905, 0.391023, 0.347069}}, 
>  {1, {0.786568, 0.391023, 0.347069}}}
> ```

```
 SeedRandom[42]; traject[fun, π, 4, 2]
```

> ```
> {{0, {0.425905, 0.391023, 0.347069, 0.453741}}, 
>  {1, {0.429179, 0.391023, 0.347069, 0.453741}}, 
>  {2, {0.783181, 0.391023, 0.347069, 0.453741}}}
> ```

More interesting, perhaps, is applying a different function

```
fun2[α_, x_] := Join[{RandomReal[α] E^x[[4]]}, Rest[x]]
SeedRandom[42]; traject[fun2, π, 4, 2]
```

> ```
> {{0, {0.425905, 0.391023, 0.347069, 0.453741}}, 
>  {1, {2.7495, 0.391023, 0.347069, 0.453741}}, 
>  {2, {1.43008, 0.391023, 0.347069, 0.453741}}}
> ```

Comment: @m_goldberger.  Many thanks.   Yes, you are right when you say that I don't have sufficient experience of Mathematica's core language.  Please believe when I say that I am trying but it hasn't been easy. The code you sent works as needed. Many thanks.  Finally, how to put everything under one function ? (Final part of my question).

Comment: @EdMendes. I have made an update that I hope will satisfy the request you made in your comment.

Comment: @m_goldberger.  Thank you ever so much.   Please correct me if I am wrong.  My intent of having everything under one function was to use it within Manipulate so that I could vary alpha and the function under fun.  Do you think that can be done with the functions above?   One last question.  Could you so kind to explain (_Function | _Symbol), please?

Comment: @EdMendes. The vertical bar (|) is [`Alternative`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Alternative.html). The pattern `f : (_Function | _Symbol)` restricts the argument `f` to have a head that is either `Symbol` or `Function`. Presumably, when it is a symbol, that symbol will name a defined function. The head `Function` identifies any pure function. Placing this restriction on the first argument isn't fool-proof, but does catch many common errors.

Comment: @EdMendes. I don't see any reason why `traject` can't be called in a `Manipulate` expression with `α` values supplied through a control such as an `Animator`, the default control type for `Manipulate` expressions that looks like a slider. Every function called in a `Manipulate` expression doesn't have to be define inside that expression; it only has to known to kernel at the time the `Manipulate` expression is evaluated.

Comment: @m_goldberger. Many thanks.   I've learned a lot.